# Will Yodlee be enhancing one-time password systems?

Tags: yodlee

Asked this on the old developer forums a couple of years ago, but we need an updated response for our users.

People report that one-time passwords (OTP) are requested just once in other data aggregator-backed apps (e.g. Mint.com). However, one-time passwords are requested repeatedly for apps that use Yodlee's services. This is a large source of frustration for our customers.

Do Yodlee have any plans to enhance one-time password processes for Yodlee users, such that the frequency of the OTP is reduced? Perhaps through logging successfully authorized IP address(es) for an item / account, and attempting to use this same machine / IP address for subsequent refresh attempts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yodlee does have capability to avoid asking OTP for every refresh if the end Site supports this behavior. We know a few financial institutions  do need OTP for every login and for these, even Yodlee would ask for OTP for these FIs.  It would be great if you can share the list of sites for which users from Yodlee gets OTP repeatedly but it's asked only once by other data aggregator. With few examples in place as samples it will be helpful for Yodlee to further analyze and do some research on this front and improve the service

Comment: Great, thanks for the information. Should we open a service request, or post the badly affected OTP sites here? Thanks!

Comment: Please open a service request and provide that service request ID. Also just to clarify, these sites which you will be providing works well with fewer/no OTP on other data aggregator?

Comment: Yes that is right - we have customers stating that their FI doesn't require more than the initial OTP with Mint.com. Cheers!

Comment: We've now opened up a service request for a customer who is having trouble with this. Would you like us to post the service request ID and FI here for your own reference? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can post the Service Request ID here and have the FI list in the SR.